# How do I count up each unique occurrence of class in list? (Python)

Tags: python

Background:

I am in the process of creating a script, which creates a production list for a small catering firm. The list should contain three columns (product type, quantity, variant)

Problem:

I have defined a class, which contains information in the order (product type, quantity, variant)

```
class vareclass:
    def __init__(self, vare, qty, meta): 
        self.vare = vare
        self.qty = qty
        self.meta = meta
```

For each product form each order, which is exported from the webshop, I add a class object to a list.

```
varer.append( vareclass(vare, qty, meta) )
```

This means, that some products appear multiple times, as more people have ordered them.

How do i count each unique ordered product variant (taking quantity into consideration)?

Comment: You can use set() for unique

Comment: Are they same same instances, or are they distinct instances with the same attribute values?  If they're the same instances, then using a `set` will work.  If they are distinct instances with the same attribute values, then it won't.

Comment: Assuming the quantities can vary from one order to another of the same product, it sounds like they are distinct instances, so the `set` solution won't work if that's the case.  You really need to create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  As it is, there's a lot of guesswork needed.

Comment: Yes I agree with @TomKarzes

Comment: Dictionary accumulation might be a viable solution in this instance. Damn, just seen a new answer with a similar suggestion, however the suggestion stands.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `__eq__` and `__hash__` and count the products with dictionary or with `collections.Counter`

```
class vareclass:

    def __init__(self, vare, qty, meta):
        self.vare = vare
        self.qty = qty
        self.meta = meta

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.vare == other.vare and self.qty == other.qty

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.vare) + hash(self.qty)

    def __repr__(self): # just for the print
        return f'{self.vare} {self.qty} {self.meta}'


varer = [vareclass('asd', 3, 'asd'), vareclass('asd', 4, 'asd'), vareclass('asd', 3, 'asd'), vareclass('zxc', 3, 'qwe')]

d = {}
for varec in varer:
    d[varec] = d.get(varec, 0) + 1
print(d) # {asd 3 asd: 2, asd 4 asd: 1, zxc 3 qwe: 1}

print(collections.Counter(varer)) # Counter({asd 3 asd: 2, asd 4 asd: 1, zxc 3 qwe: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), since sets are a collection of unique objects.

Comment: *"This means, that some products appear multiple times"* - ```Set``` doesn't work in this case.